# Position sublevel menu beside its parent in CSS

Tags: html, css, menu

I have a menu that is working fine, but I want put a new sublevel on it, and if I put directly, when new options show they hide the othes option of menu.

here a pic http://www.potrusmaximus.uphero.com/dudas/menu.jpg

I want that new options show it next to the selected not down. 
thx

Here my css and Html.

```css
#menu-bar {
  display: inline-block;
}
html[xmlns] #menu-bar {
  display: block;
}
* html #menu-bar {
  height: 1%;
}

#menu-bar {
  width: 1010px;
  margin: 3px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 5px 5px 5px !important;
  max-height: 42px;
  line-height: 100%;
  border-radius: 43px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 43px;
  -moz-border-radius: 43px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 14px #949494;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 14px #949494;
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 14px #949494;

  background: #f7f7f7;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f7f7f7 0%, #c4c4c4 16%, #666666 39%, #666666 56%, #545454 68%, #292929 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #f7f7f7), color-stop(16%, #c4c4c4), color-stop(39%, #666666), color-stop(56%, #666666), color-stop(68%, #545454), color-stop(100%, #292929));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f7f7f7 0%, #c4c4c4 16%, #666666 39%, #666666 56%, #545454 68%, #292929 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f7f7f7 0%, #c4c4c4 16%, #666666 39%, #666666 56%, #545454 68%, #292929 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f7f7f7 0%, #c4c4c4 16%, #666666 39%, #666666 56%, #545454 68%, #292929 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f7f7f7 0%, #c4c4c4 16%, #666666 39%, #666666 56%, #545454 68%, #292929 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr="#f7f7f7", endColorstr="#292929", GradientType=0 );

  border: solid 2px #B8B8B8;
  position:relative;
  z-index:999;
}
#menu-bar li {                      /* define los li*/
  margin: 0px 8px 6px 8px;
  padding: 0px 18px 0px 17px !important;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}
#menu-bar a {                /*define los enlace*/
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-family: georgia;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #EDEBEB;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 10px 10px 10px !important;

  margin-bottom: 6px;
  border-radius: 29px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 29px;
  -moz-border-radius: 29px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #000000;
}
#menu-bar li ul li a {
  margin: 0;
}
/*#menu-bar .active a, */#menu-bar li:hover > a {          

  background: #ffffff;
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 18%, #ebe8eb 32%, #d2d0d2 51%, #9a989a 74%, #434243 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, #ffffff), color-stop(18%, #ffffff), color-stop(32%, #ebe8eb), color-stop(51%, #d2d0d2), color-stop(74%, #9a989a), color-stop(100%, #434243));
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 18%, #ebe8eb 32%, #d2d0d2 51%, #9a989a 74%, #434243 100%);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 18%, #ebe8eb 32%, #d2d0d2 51%, #9a989a 74%, #434243 100%);
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 18%, #ebe8eb 32%, #d2d0d2 51%, #9a989a 74%, #434243 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 18%, #ebe8eb 32%, #d2d0d2 51%, #9a989a 74%, #434243 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr="#ffffff", endColorstr="#434243", GradientType=1 );

  color: #141414;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #363636;
}
#menu-bar ul li:hover a, #menu-bar li:hover li a {       /* coplores iluminacion*/
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: #ebebeb;
  -box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
}
#menu-bar ul a:hover {   /*elementos submenu seleccionados*/
  background: #0399D4 !important;
  background: linear-gradient(top,  #87ECEC,  #0186BA) !important;
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #87ECEC,  #0186BA) !important;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#87ECEC), to(#0186BA)) !important;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #87ECEC,  #0186BA) !important;
  color: #141414 !important;
  border-radius: 29px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #FFFFFF;
}
#menu-bar ul {             /*define la caja del submenu*/
  background: #262626;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #5e5e5e 31%, #525252 45%, #050505 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #262626), color-stop(31%, #5e5e5e), color-stop(45%, #525252), color-stop(100%, #050505));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #5e5e5e 31%, #525252 45%, #050505 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #5e5e5e 31%, #525252 45%, #050505 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #5e5e5e 31%, #525252 45%, #050505 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #262626 0%, #5e5e5e 31%, #525252 45%, #050505 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr="#262626", endColorstr="#050505", GradientType=0 );

  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 !important;
  width: 201px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 42px;
  left: 0;
  border: solid 2px #B8B8B8;
  border-radius: 29px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 29px;
  -moz-border-radius: 29px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #949494;
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #949494;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #949494;
}
#menu-bar li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#menu-bar ul li {
  float: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
#menu-bar ul a {        /* enlaces submenus*/ 
  padding:10px 1px 10px 15px !important;
  color:#242424;
  font-size:12px;
  font-style:normal;
  font-family:georgia;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #b8b2b8;
}
#menu-bar ul li:first-child > a {
  border-top-left-radius: 29px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 29px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 29px;
  border-top-right-radius: 29px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 29px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 29px;
}
#menu-bar ul li:last-child > a {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 29px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 29px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 29px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 29px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 29px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 29px;
}
#menu-bar:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu-bar">
 <li class="active"><a href="http://40kpm.blogspot.com.es/">POTRUS MAXIMUS</a></li>
 <li><a href="/p/codex.html">CODEX & DATASLATES</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">LISTAS</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">1850 Puntos</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">1500 Puntos</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Por raza</a></li> 
 </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">BIBLIOTECA</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Horus Heresy</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Warhammer 40K</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Warhammer Fantasy</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Fantasia Épica</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Ciencia Ficción</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Otros</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">REVISTAS</a>
 <ul>
   <li><a href="#">White Dwarf Weekly</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://40kpm.blogspot.com.es/p/white-dwarf-weekly_8.html">ISSUES 1-42</a>
        <li><a href="http://40kpm.blogspot.com.es/p/white-dwarf-weekly-issues.html">ISSUES 43-84</a>
        </li></li></ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Otras</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">TUTORIALES</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you only submitted the relevant code (not so much of the CSS formatting) in a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

i can fix the sub menu design if you want to, but in the general idea, this it what you'r looking for?

```
#menu-bar ul ul
{
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}

#menu-bar li:hover > ul
{
    display: block;
}
```

live example: http://jsfiddle.net/r9Lxodvb/2/